# Ethereum block is active from 1 day and 15 hours

Tags: transactions

my transacion status shown IN for to address. What does this mean? This transaction is in block for more than 1 day and 11 hours...Blok confirmation are increasing but i am not sure when it will credit to my account..

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at the list of transactions for an account on Etherscan or the like, "in" indicated that the account in question is the recipient of the transaction (as opposed to "out," indicating that the transaction is *from* that account).

As soon as the transaction makes it into a block, its effects (such as an ether transfer) have happened. There's nothing else to wait for.

If you're not seeing the balance you were expecting, please provide more information about where you're looking (ideally a link to the transaction or account) and what you expected to see.